# How can a wizard maximize the area of bursts and blasts?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard

I'm hoping to build a power play wizard (or hybrids) with large  bursts. Is there any way to Enlarge Spell more than once (like with the talent "Enlarge Spell")?

In short, I would love to know how to maximize the area of a wizard's bursts and blasts (other than Enlarge Spell).

Comment: Hi and welcome! You're going in a lot of directions at once here. Could you narrow this down to a specific aspect or give specific DPR targets?

Comment: Ok, would love to know how to maximize area of burst and blast for wizard (if any other than Enlarge Spell). Thank you

Comment: Is the White Lotus thing actually related to the area maximization question? If not, it can and should be asked in its own separate question. I haven't read the White Lotus talents, so I'm unaware here.

Comment: No, white lotus has just to do with doing damages more time in one round. Repeating a burst each round could help to make multiple damages to different enemies.

Answer (score 1):

**The Resounding Thunder feat is the most widely used solution.**
First you have to find a way to add Thunder to your attacks, the easiest is probably the 16th level feature of the paragon path Malec-Keth Janissary.

Another, in my opinion inferior option it the Master of Flame paragon path. Both get bigger bursts at level 16, but adding fire is difficult.

*Optimizing Wizard at-will powers if a wasted effort*, Wizards get some of the best Encounter attack powers, all of them Standard actions. By the time you could get White Lotus Master Riposte, you have 4 great Standards. If you are indeed optimized, the fight is usually over in 3 rounds. When would you use those at-wills?

Optimizing those encounter powers with Enlarge Spell for example will help At-wills as well, just do not *concentrate* on at-wills.

---

You can choose from different builds:

- If you want damage a Genasi with the Elemental Empowerment feat is quite strong from early heroic.
- If you want control, you have to take different Encounter powers and feats, but it is really strong from Paragon.

More about the possible builds you can find in the [Wizards forums](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3292096).

Comment: Would being a dragonborn with the dragonsomething rod (level 4 implement) help or is it worded in a way that's incompatible with your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking at things a little too linearly.  When it comes to 4e, most realistic battle maps aren't going to be so large that you need to keep attacking larger areas.  These bigger fields are likely not even actual fields, but twisting corridors no wider than three squares for the smallest dimension. Plus, when it comes to D&D (especially 4e), there is a surprising amount of dependency on other characters, even ones of the same build.

Thus, even when you have the easiest method (Enlarge) sitting on your belt, your party is your biggest game changes.  If you get your fellow adventurers to use Control tactics to push and pull your enemies into effective groupings.  When you consider likely areas for combat, your ability to force and predict enemy movement will get you the most out of your AoE abilities.